# Data binding happening only once rivetsjs

Tags: rivets.js

I am in a situation to use rivetsjs, and to get data binding. So I just started to work in it.

What i did  was

```
            studentList.get().done(function () {//after a jax call
            debugger;
            rview = rivets.bind(_this.$el.find("#hello"), studentList.getData());
            console.log(studentList.getData());
            rview.unbind();
        });


        _this.$el.find("#Click").click(function() {
            studentList.refresh().done(function() {//aFter a ajax cal
                var getmodel = rview.bindings[0].model;
                var getdata = studentList.getData();
                rivets.bind(_this.$el.find("#hello"),getdata);
                rview.sync();
            });
        });
```

The Html is

```
<div id="hello">
  <div rv-each-item="studentList">
      <span>{ item.name }</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

1.I am getting a value from json file(which acts a DB). At initial time the data from the json file is binding well.
2.But when i change a value in the json file and click a button the second ajax call works fine, but binding is not happening.
i.e second time binding is not working

What i want is, when update the JSON file. i want to bind the data to the DOM